# Type inference can be erroneous for optional properties in merged objects (e.g. options)

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I recently encountered the following situation with TypeScript, which will frequently occur in practice:

```
interface Options {
  foo?: number;
  bar?: string;
}

const defaultOptions = {
  foo: 123,
  bar: 'abc',
} as const satisfies Options;

function f(options: Options) {
  const fullOptions = { // Type is inferred as {foo: number; bar: string} (regardless of satisfies)
    ...defaultOptions,
    ...options,
  } as const satisfies Required<Options>; // This is not guaranteed and should be marked as error!
  // The actual type is still just Options because the props of defaultOptions may be overwritten.

  console.log(fullOptions);

  return fullOptions.bar.toUpperCase();
}

f({foo: 456}); // Works
f({foo: 456, bar: undefined}) // Runtime error!
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

As you can see, TypeScript does not complain in the `satisfies Required<Options>` part although it should. Is this intentional behavior or a bug?

Comment: See [ms/TS#57408](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57408) It's intentional behavior; if you care about doing things where `undefined` properties are different from missing properties, then you should use the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NnoKkm).  But the normal approach here is just to avoid such situations. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Ah I see, yes that makes it clear I think. I wonder whether `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` should be the default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is behaving as intended; see [microsoft/TypeScript#57408](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57408) for an authoritative answer.

Generally speaking, for [optional properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#optional-properties), TypeScript doesn't make a distinction between properties which are *missing* and those which are *present with an `undefined` value*.  For a lot of purposes this is fine. For both `const opts = {foo: 456}` and `const opts = {foo: 456, bar: undefined}`, `opts.bar` is `undefined`.  But there are some situations in which there is an observable difference, and the behavior of [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) is one such situation.

For a long time this was just the way things were. But enough people were unsatisfied that the feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#13195](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13195) received a lot of community support.  Ultimately, TypeScript introduced [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#43947](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43947).  With that compiler option enabled, you will still see `undefined` if you *read* from an optional property, but there will be an error if you try to write `undefined` *to* an optional property (unless `undefined` is explicitly included in its value type).  If we enable that, then the following code produces a compiler warning:

```
f({foo: 456, bar: undefined}) // error!
// Argument of type '{ foo: number; bar: undefined; }' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'Options' with 'exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true'. 
// Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

And you can't accidentally overwrite an existing property with `undefined`.

---

So if you really care about this, you might want to enable `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes`.  Note that this compiler option is *not* included in [the `--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict).  Originally this was going to be `--strictOptionalProperties` and included.  But if you read the discussion at [microsoft/TypeScript#44421](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44421) you will see that it was considered too much of a breaking change.  The problem is that there's a large amount of real world code, including TypeScript's own libraries, that use optional properties.  But since `{x?: string}` and `{x?: string | undefined}` were historically equivalent, what should happen to existing declarations like `{x?: string}`? Did the original author intend to allow or disallow `undefined`?  There's no way to tell programmatically.  That means someone would have to go through each and every optional property and make that decision.  Otherwise, the next release of TypeScript would just enforce "disallow `undefined`" everywhere, and lots of things break.

So, for better or worse, they moved it out of `--strict`, renamed it to `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` at [microsoft/TypeScript#44626](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/44626), and told people to use it at their own risk.  Maybe someday the ecosystem will be ready to include the flag in `--strict`, but until and unless that happens, you need to decide whether the benefits outweigh the risks in your own code.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-zePDAMQgFyrLnYZCdurodH9yBQIdcnlj87ro3AOVjiAADzZ5Tg6gACkrI25JoWkyLkoCYCBHAOU9SCZYCUEcRcQhAHp10RZE+l3fdD1lE8RwQqZxCgsggA)